# Как в документе оставить амперсанд

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

В документе присутствует & ЕСЕНАМАН М.&., 
выдает ошибку:

> The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.

Понятно, что можно поменять на `&amp;`, но нужно чтобы она содержала именно амперсанд, так просят заказчики. Как можно это положение исправить.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно соблюдать те правила экранирования, которые требуются в конкретном формате и убирать это экранирование если формат меняется и правила экранирования другие.

Например, если у вас в базе есть какая-либо строка, то при формировании XML нужно автоматически экранировать все символы `<`, `>`, `&` для поддержания целостности XML-документа. Если вы получаете откуда-то XML, потом его парсите и записываете отдельные значения в базу, нужно обязательно преобразовывать сущности в соответствующие символы (ну и экранировать всё что может повредить базе).

**Плохие примеры:**

1. Для правильного отображения на HTML страницах в php-скриптах иногда встречаются попытки преобразовать всё в сущности, потом это все записывается в базу, а при формировании страницы просто вставляется переменная без экранирования (а вот если это значение оказывается в какой-то ссылке или в JS - получается плохо);
2. Все, что попадает в скрипт экранируют в стиле Си, чтобы защититься от SQL-инъекций, но забывают экранировать LIKE строки или повторно экранируют после модификации данных. В результате на страницах можно увидеть лишние слеши.

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какой документ. Можно например заменить все `&` на `&amp;`

Comment: да можно заменить но от нас просят чтобы передавали именно & потому как в БД так записано и их программа уже давно так работает, и от нас так просят теперь

Comment: Не обязательно менять в базе, или в документе, можно менять "на лету"